# How to achieve build variants with python?

Tags: python

In C/C++ apps I've developed slight build variants by defining a high-level macro

```
#define PRODUCTION_BUILD
#define DEBUG_BUILD
...
```

Is there some kind of equivalent I can use to conditionally include components of a larger python app?

Comment: isn't this what branches are for in your VCS?

Comment: @AdamSmith: Not really. Branches are for separating versions of code, not binaries. It's entirely normal to want to compile a release in the develop branch (so you can test it and then merge your develop branch to the stable branch).

Comment: @VincentSavard ah perhaps I've not understood what a macro does in C then. I'd assumed it was modifying something inside the code (thus: different code, different branches).

Comment: @AdamSmith: Take asserts, for example. You want to make sure a list isn't empty when it's called by your function, so you add a `assert(!my_list.is_empty())`. During development, you want to see if your assertion is false, and you want to see an error message. But when you build a release, you don't want to users to see this kind of error (instead you may want to log it and gracefully fail). So your assert is defined in a way that it only does something if you're building a debug binary, not a release binay. That's where a macro is useful.

Comment: @VincentSavard awesome, thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't have a pre processor like C/C++. It doesn't have true constants either. You can, by convention, define "constants" by typing them in full caps like

```
DEBUG_BUILD = True
```

but nothing other than convention will prevent it from being modified. If you only need two variants (debug/production), you can use

```
__debug__
```

like

```
if __debug__:
  do something
else:
  do something else
```

This variable will be set depending on the optimize flag when running a python script, or by the PYTHONOPTIMIZE environment variable.

The nice thing about using __debug__ is that it will throw a SyntaxError if you attempt to modify its value.